# Extrude Region (Vertex Normals) stopped working properly

Tags: extrude

in one file i used to be able to create bulky pieces like these
[image]

by applying extrusion along normals on the loop of faces like that:
[image]

[image]

at some point in started working like the regular Extrude Region, giving results like these: 
[image]

also, as you can see, creating new object in the same scene does not help, only creating new file does.

link to the file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/43119

i would like to know how to restore the usual functionality and what i might have done to cause this.

Comment: It is due to the pivot point : set it back to median point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extrude region with *vertex normals* behaves nearly like extrude region if the pivot point is set to *individual origins*.

Set the pivot point back to *median point* to have the expected behavior :

[image]